# Spring 2.5 localeChangeInterceptor somehow did not work

Tags: spring, locale

I'm trying to use localeChangeInterceptor to load different language depends on the locale, but somehow it never changes. It is always the defaultLocale.

Here is how I set up the beans

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Register the message.properties -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="message" />
</bean>
```

The URL I use to access different locale is:

```
    http://localhost:8080/something/message/login?language=zh_CN
```

---

I think I have a reason why it isn't working, it is because I'm use annotation for URL mapping. So is there another way to setup the localeChangeInterceptor with annotation?

Answer (score 1):

So after I notice the reason why it is not working is because I'm using annotation for URL mapping, the rest of it is simple.

Instead of using ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping, I should use DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping. And this is how to set it up.

```
<bean id="annotationMapper" 
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As you have set the paramName manually, you should use the following url:
http://localhost:8080/something/message/login?language=zh_CN

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong link, I was testing with different paramName to see if that makes a different. I did use language=zh_CN at beginning